# PostgreSQL: how can queries possibly be "immutable" / functional?

Tags: postgresql

I've read that PostgreSQL can have "functional" indexes.  For that you need the *immutable* keyword.

Seen that PostgreSQL is a CRUD DB I don't understand at all how it can possibly work in a functional way.

If there's an update or a delete to the DB, how can a past query guarantee that the result of the same query is always going to be the same?

Comment: the inclusion of a functional feature does not mean that the language is purely functional, nore does the primary paradigm being something else preclude a functional feature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are getting confused with functional programming languages.

Anyway, a functional index is used to speed up access to data where queries that are accessing the data are using database functions.

By way of example, a query such as `select blah from foo where sqrt(blah)=4` would have to perform the `sqrt()` operation for each value of `blah`. You could optimise this by pre-calculating all values of `sqrt(blah)` in a [functional index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-expressional.html): `create index foo_func on foo (sqrt(blah));`

This is where immutability comes in. A function is immutable if and only if the same input will always give the same output. Functional indexes can only use [immutable functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/xfunc-volatility.html). This guarantees that any queries for a given value and related functional index value will always return the same result.